# How do I get an OAuth access token in python?

Tags: python, oauth, dropbox

(I asked this on superuser but got no response ...)

I'm trying to follow the tutorial for the Dropbox API at http://taught-process.blogspot.com/2012/05/asdlasd-asda-sd-asd-asdasd.html

But when I get to the last part

```
#Print the token for future reference
print access_token
```

What I get back is

```
<dropbox.session.OAuthToken object at 0x1102d4210>
```

How do I get the actual token? It should look something like:

```
oauth_token_secret=xxxxxxx&oauth_token=yyyyyyy
```

(I'm on a Mac)

Answer (score 1):

Look around in the properties and methods of the object, to do so apply "dir" on the object.
In your case:

```
dir(access_token)
```

I'm pretty sure you're gonna find in this object something that will give you the token you need.

Comment: I support this answer because it is the logical way to get more info on used class. In the list you can find `access_token.key` and `access_token.secret` values.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right object, yes. But you're dealing with an instance of a class.

```
<dropbox.session.OAuthToken object at 0x1102d4210>
```

This is an instance of the OAuthToken object the Dropbox SDK created for you. This token appears to have two attributes: `key` and `secret`. These would be your token key and secret. This is what you're after.

You can access them like this:

```
print access_token.key
print access_token.secret
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same tutorial for the Dropbox API at http://taught-process.blogspot.com/2012/05/asdlasd-asda-sd-asd-asdasd.html

Ended up with the following script that worked for me

```
# Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
from dropbox import client, rest, session

# Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developer website
APP_KEY = '3w7xv4d9lrkc7c3'
APP_SECRET = '1v5f80mztbd3m9t'

# ACCESS_TYPE should be 'dropbox' or 'app_folder' as configured for your app
ACCESS_TYPE = 'app_folder'

sess = session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TYPE)
request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()
url = sess.build_authorize_url(request_token)

# Make the user sign in and authorize this token
print "url:", url
print "Please visit this website and press the 'Allow' button, then hit 'Enter' here."
raw_input()

# This will fail if the user didn't visit the above URL
access_token = sess.obtain_access_token(request_token)

#Print the token for future reference
print access_token.key
print access_token.secret
```